# Customize the facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I have put up my code in jsfiddle. The link is http://jsfiddle.net/QWAYE/1/ I have also put another sample code in this link http://jsfiddle.net/MCb5K/ The first link is working fine for me and i want to make it look like the second link but dont know what changes i need to do. Please suggest what change i need to do. Also i want to display only the number of person who likes the page and not the name. Right now the name of person is displayed and not the number like how it is showing in the second link. How to do that?

**Note:** I dont want the send button and the rest of the text, only need like button and the number of likes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the like plugin on the facebook developer page.
Go to this link and you will be able to display what you want on the facebook iframe.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You select layout style -> button_count